# Open SSMS query window from c#

Tags: c#, ssms

From C#-code I would like to open a tab/query window in SQL Server Management System, SSMS (which can be assumed to be open already), for an existing stored procedure (for which I have the object_id). So, I would then obtain the same as if used the Object Explorer in SSMS, right-clicked on the stored procedure and selected "Modify", but instead doing it from Visual Studio
with c#.
Is this possible? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: prolly by building SSMS adding ... which is too broad for SO answer ...

Comment: This sounds like a rather awkward way of maintaining your procedure code. I'd strongly recommend looking into using a Visual Studio Database project to edit and deploy procedure and other code.

Comment: If you really want to control another application using C#, I suggest you to use something like AutoIT. There's even a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoItX.Dotnet/)

Comment: See [SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/ssdt/) for best practice.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.Why this would be interesting for me is that I sometimes have to make changes in a large number of stored procedures.
It would simply be a lot easier to handle this from a UI from which I could open the sp:s via listboxes or similar, Instead of  having to manually switch to SSMS, look up the sp among a big number, etc.
I had googled this without success so I thought it might be difficult.

Comment: Imagine you could simply do a search and replace in procedure code file in your VS solution. This sure will beat an automated process to open procedures in SSMS.

Comment: Did you go and have a look at VS Database projects? The ability to edit code and publish to configurable target environments plus the added benefit of having your code under version control is best practice. You don't even need a paid SKU of VS - this works just fine with free VS Community Edition.

Comment: I downloaded and installed SSDT to VS (Community) and after studying some tutorials managed to create a project and then import the database and it worked to do some changes in tables. However, so far I fail to use Find-function to get me into the Alter Procedure -version of sp:s. The Find-function only takes me to the Create Procedure-version, in which I cannot do any changes (and then Execute to make the them come through). So, unless I can figure out how to get into the Alter-version with the Find-function ,I still have to do it manually and I remain in same situation as before.

Comment: You don't need to rely on creating an ALTER script - Publish will take care by producing a DROP PROCEDURE and CREATE PROCEDURE script for you. Use the "Preview Script" of the "Publish" task to see what will be executed on publishing your project. Granted, this is a huge learning curve to get into Database projects but it is really how it is intended to be.

Comment: Your comments helped me, so now I can manage to do the thing I asked about. Thanks.